# Vue prop validation getting executed every time there is input on another component

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I have a Vue component as follows:

```
<template>
<div>
    <div class="sel-square"
        @click="selectGender('Male')"
        :class="{ active : value === 'Male'}">
    <div class="sel-square__img">
        <img src="~Img/lp_v1/fam-male.png"
            alt="male" />
    </div>
    <div class="sel-square__caption">
        Male
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="sel-square"
    @click="selectGender('Female')"
    :class="{ active : value === 'Female'}">
    <div class="sel-square__img">
        <img src="~Img/lp_v1/fam-female.png"
            alt="female" />
    </div>
    <div class="sel-square__caption">
        Female
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
props : { 
    value: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    validator: (value) => {
        console.log("Validating", value)
        return ['Male', 'Female'].includes(value)
    }   
    }   
},  
methods :{
    selectGender(gender) {
    console.log("Emiting input", gender)
    this.$emit('input', gender)
    }   
}   
}   
</script>
```

I am using this in my main App as:

```
<GenderSelector v-model="gender"></GenderSelector>
```

The issue I am facing is that the 'validator' runs 3-4 times the very first time I refresh the page and after that it keep executing on every keypress on another input element I have on the same page.
Just to be clear, the console output keeps showing "Validating Male" again and again and the "Emiting input" only shows on console when I click.

Is Vue validating props again and again on every input event? Its unlikely, so what am I doing wrong here?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/5090/

Comment: make sure that you are not updating your mode multiple time

Comment: the v-model='gender' is the only reference to gender in the app. I am not changing gender directly anywhere in the app.

Comment: if it is running 3-4 times then make sure you are not calling the component that many times. You should probably add a demo on jsfiddle so we can quickly inspect the problem

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/4544/  Thanks for the suggestion. Here you go, just check console output to see the behaviour.

Comment: What is the `<input v-mode>`? do you mean `v-model` it seems like it's not needed

Comment: i guess if you remove it, it works

Comment: Always check your console errors

Comment: did you check the jsfiddle, where do you see v-mode ?

Comment: html line 23....

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, its the older fiddle without the updated html. https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/5090/  this should help you identify the problem

Comment: everything seems to work as intended here where do you see the 3-4 console.logs?

Comment: When I type in the input, I keep getting console logs for "Validating Male" on every key press

Comment: That is the intended behaviour

Comment: You mean all prop validations in the page will run if I do any key input on any element? It feels like a bug that interacting with one completely independent component with make validations runs for all other components.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167976/discussion-between-rane-and-samayo).

Comment: Not all just that one component

Comment: I was trying to solve it assigning a different prop name than `value` but it doesn't work, and with slots neither.. A workaround will be deleting the entire validator and in the `selectGender` method add the validation, like: `if(['Male', 'Female'].includes(gender)){ this.$emit('input', gender) }` . Maybe it helps meanwhile.

Comment: @rane did you find the solution?

Comment: @boussadjra I am using vuelidate and typescript for proper validations of input. I think the props validation is not supposed to be used for validation. If validations are not met, it produces a warning message in the console only when development mode is used. So it's not really for validation, but for development hints. For validation, I use vuelidate and typescript etc. Also, this gets stripped on production build, so no worries on multiple calls.

Answer (score 1):

That's perfectly normal, you are not doing anything wrong. Prop validation is triggered whenever the component re-renders like when a prop changes.

When using `v-model` on a component, whenever you emit `input` event, the component re-renders because it effectively updates the `value` prop. The component itself doesn't update the `value` prop but rather it's parent. because `v-model` is more or less a shorthand of `:value="value" @input="value = $event"`. So the component re-renders and the validation is triggered.

You shouldn't worry about it, I would argue that you don't need the `validator` as your component is likely to always emit valid values.